# Optimal solution to 2 simultaneous linear inequalities (integer solution)

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

I have the following inequalities.

$$a_1x \leq b_1y + c_1$$

$$b_2y \leq a_2x + c_2$$

$a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2$ are known positive integers with $b_1 <= a_1$ and $a_2 <= b_2$, and either $b_1 < a_1$ or $a_2 < a_2$ (or both).

$c_1,c_2$ are known non-negative integers.

$x,y$ are unknown non-negative integers.

I'd like to (efficiently) find the maximal values of $x$ and $y$. I believe there should be a unique solution (since increasing $x$ can only violate the first inequality and increasing $y$ can only violate the second, implying an iterative approach that is guaranteed to terminate).

Naively "solving" the inequalities by substitution I produced the following.

$$x \leq \frac{(b_1c_2 + b_2c_1)}{(a_1b_2 - b_1a_2)}$$

$$y \leq \frac{(a_2c_1 + a_1c_2)}{(a_1b_2 - b_1a_2)}$$

I had hoped that evaluating the RHSs and rounding down to the nearest integer would always yield the optimal solution. Mostly it works, but there are occasional invalid results. Example of invalid result:

$a_1=558, a_2=32, b_1=32, b_2=39, c_1=177, c_2=12374$

This yields:

$$x \leq 19.4  \implies  x = 19$$

$$y \leq 333.2  \implies  y = 333$$

But this violates the second inequality since $$b_2y = 12987 > 12982 = a_2x + c_2$$

Edit: considering the problem geometrically makes it easy to see why this can happen.

I'm vaguely aware of the Simplex Algorithm in Linear Programming, but I'm not sure if it's appropriate due to the integer constraints on the solution (I could be wrong). I'm also vaguely aware of Integer Programming, but this particular problem seems to be a simpler special case.

Can anyone suggest an approach which works without iteration/recursion?

[Many thanks; please be gentle, this is my first post]

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thank you for your feedback. I agree with your comment in the general case of these equations. But, with the extra constraints specified here, I believe there should always be a solution (X,Y) where both X and Y are maximal (this is what I tried to explain with my poorly-explained remark "I believe there should be a unique solution..."). Consider an algorithm starting with a known valid solution such as (0,0). Since incrementing X can not invalidate the current value of Y (and vice versa), it should be possible to keep incrementing both until the optimum is found.

Comment: Right, I realized this as I started looking at the problem more closely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you should be careful about saying "the maximal values of $x$ and $y$" since the maximal value of $x$ does not necessarily coincide with the maximal value of $y$, and you can only maximize one thing at a time. But in this case, there is a clear point where both $x$ and $y$ are maximized.

(By the way, I hope you don't mind me switching to lowercase variables in my answer.)

Unfortunately, a problem of this type can be arbitrarily badly behaved. It's possible that the fractional solution $(\frac{b_1 c_2 - b_2 c_1}{a_1 b_2 - b_1 a_2}, \frac{a_2 c_1 - a_1 c_2}{a_1 b_2 - b_1 a_2})$ is arbitrarily far from the optimal integer solution. In fact, it's possible to make this fractional solution arbitrarily large and still have $(x,y)=(0,0)$ be the only integer solution.

The best approach varies depending on what kind of parameters $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2,c_1,c_2$ you have. Here's a simple approach that will be fine if the feasible region is not too "thin".

Rewriting the constraints as $\frac{a_1}{b_1} x - \frac{c_1}{b_1} \le y \le \frac{a_2}{b_2}x + \frac{c_2}{b_2}$, we see that for a particular (integer) value of $x$, if the lower and upper bounds on $y$ are at least $1$ apart, then there will be an integer solution between them. This happens when $$x \le \frac{b_1 c_2 + b_2 c_1 - b_1 b_2}{a_1 b_2 - a_2 b_1}$$
which is a bit smaller than the optimal fractional value of $x$. So we can start by trying each value of $x$ between $\lfloor \frac{b_1 c_2 + b_2 c_1 - b_1 b_2}{a_1 b_2 - a_2 b_1}\rfloor$ and $\lfloor \frac{b_1 c_2 + b_2 c_1}{a_1 b_2 - b_1 a_2}\rfloor$. For each such $x$, let $y = \lfloor \frac{a_2}{b_2} x + \frac{c_2}{b_2}\rfloor$ and check that this satisfies the other constraint, $a_1x \le b_1y + c_1$. We'll succeed for at least the smallest possible $x$ we try; if we take the largest successful value, we'll get the optimal integer solution. (Maybe try them in order from largest to smallest to save time.)

We'll have to try around $\frac1{m_1 - m_2}$ values of $x$, where $m_1 = \frac{a_1}{b_1}$ and $m_2 = \frac{a_2}{b_2}$ are the two slopes. This works well if the two constraints are far from parallel.

The constraints on the parameters mean that $m_1 \ge 1 \ge m_2$, with $m_1 > m_2$ (which is good, because if $m_2 \ge m_1$, the region is unbounded). We still run into trouble when $m_1$ and $m_2$ are both close to $1$, because then we have to try lots of values of $x$. For example, consider the system of inequalities
$$
   \begin{cases}
       (2n)x \le (2n)y + (2n-1) \\
       (2n)y \le (2n-2)x + 1
   \end{cases}
$$
Here, the optimal fractional solution is $(x,y) = (n, n - 1 + \frac1{2n})$, but the optimal integer solution is $(0,0)$.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, which I'm still digesting. I realized that the A,B constraints should have been specified more strictly. In addition to what is there, I should also have said B1 is always <= A1 and A2 is always <= B2. I'll try to edit the question accordingly.

Comment: So in other words, $m_1 \ge 1$ and $m_2 \le 1$, excluding the case $m_1 = m_2 = 1$, which rules out all the bad cases (and also means that the only thin region occurs when $m_1, m_2 \approx 1$, and it doesn't matter if we should slice with respect to $x$ or $y$).

Comment: Thank you for your help. BTW I think there's a error in the numerator of the upper bound of the x range (sentence starting "So we can start by...") where -b2c1 should be +b2c1.

Comment: You're right, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest to define the problem as a Integer Linear Program.

$ \max (x) + \max (y) = \max (x + y) $

subject to

$\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
a_1x – b_1y \leq c_1 \\
-a_2x + b_2y \leq c_2 \\
x, y \in N
\end{array} \right. $

*Example*
For $a_1=558$, $a_2=32$, $b_1=32$, $b_2=39$, $c_1=177$, $c_2=12374$ the model leads to the optimal solution $x^*=19$ and $y^*=332$.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Can you be more specific about what you mean by "the model leads to"? I understand that there are various different approaches in Integer Linear Programming (branch and bound, branch and cut, etc) - could you indicate which you used here please.

Comment: @DUZn7u6Xf I used _branch and bound_ algorithm adopted by Solver embedded in Excel.

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification.